# To create Automation - powershell

Tags: powershell-4.0

I am trying to do automation where the scenario is like: I am having a text file ABC.txt which contains all numbers :

ABC.txt:

```
12234

12345

123455
```

Through the PowerShell scripting, I want to have the output in a text file like :

```
Sunny day

Rainy Day

Windy day

This is 12234

This is 12345

This is 123455
```

So I have performed the below scripting:

```
$File1 = @((Get-Content "E:\ABC.txt"))
For($a = 0;$a -lt $File1.count;$a++){-join ("This is ", $File1[$a]) | Out-File -FilePath "E:\XYZ.txt" -Append}
```

The above script is showing output in XYZ.txt file:-

```
This is 12234

This is 12345

This is 123455
```

Can you please let me how to add the following on top of the above output:

```
Sunny day

Rainy Day

Windy day
```